# Dictionary attack on SHA1 hash

Tags: python, hash, sha1, dictionary-attack

The following is my code. I have been trying to fix the code to perform dictionary attack on a hash (SHA-1) and I am getting the following result.
P.S. I am a beginner to coding.

```
import hashlib
import random
#plug in the hash that needs to be cracked
hash_to_crack = "5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8"
#direct the location of the dictionary file
dict_file = "C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/dictionary.txt"

def main():
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if hashlib.sha1(line.encode()).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
                print ("The password is %s") % (line);
                return ""
    print ("Failed to crack the hash!")
    return ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The result:

```
RESTART: C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/datest1.py
The password is %s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/datest1.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/datest1.py", line 13, in main
    print ("The password is %s") % (line);
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please, don't use capslock for writing question. Also, take some time to explain what you are trying to do. To learn how to ask better questions, please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This will help others to help you. If you have questions, provide your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use [hashcat](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat) instead of trying to program this yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line is not valid python3 syntax: (EDIT: it's a valid syntax ! But not what you want :) )

```
print ("The password is %s") % (line);
```

Use this instead:

```
print ("The password is %s" % line)
```

Also, accordig to the error message, line might be None.

Comment: See my answer:  the syntax is fine in Python 3 - it just doesn't at all do what they hoped it would do ;-)  If the syntax were wrong, they would gotten a `SyntaxError ` instead.  The problem is that that `print()` function returns `None`, and _then_ `None % a_string` makes no sense (which _is_ the error message they got).

Answer (score 2):

You're using Python 3, where `print` is a function.  The line:

```
print ("The password is %s") % (line)
```

calls the function `print` with the argument `"The password is %s"`.  The function returns `None`.  Then `None % (line)` gives the error message you see.

Most idiomatic is to write the line this way instead:

```
print("The password is", line)
```

Other ways that would work:

```
print("The password is %s" % line)
print(("The password is %s") % (line))
```